# Coroutine related functions dont work when I build the project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I have 2 scripts that feature Coroutines, and in the unity editor they work fine. But when i build the project, the funtions in both scripts start behaving weird (slow and late input).

This is one of them from the player script.
Invistime is 2, invistimedelta = 0.05.

```
private IEnumerator BeInvincible()
{
    
   isInvincible = true;
    for (float i = 0; i < invistime; i += invistimedelta)
    {
        // Flashing
        if (sprite.color == new Color(1, 1, 1, 1))
        {
            sprite.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            sprite.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(invistimedelta);
    }
    sprite.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    isInvincible = false;
    Debug.Log("frames done");

}
```

Biggest problem is that the script featuring the coroutines, work different in entirly, not just in the courotines.

Anyone who knows what's going on?

Comment: What platform are you running your builds on? How fast is it running (i.e. FPS)? Keep in mind that WaitForSeconds isn't necessarily precise.

Comment: @Bart Build is in windows. FPS is in build steady 60. In Unity its around 800 FPS. Is these another method I can use instead of WaitforSeconds?

Comment: Try and take away the startup cost.  For example, create the coroutine before starting it (`private IEnumerator co = BeInvincible;`) and create the Wait (`WaitForSeconds myWait = new WaitForSeconds(invistimedelta)`  Then in your coroutine just `yield return myWait` and start it with `StartCoroutine(co)`  This will at least optimize things.